# C# Hide parent form when child form is active

Tags: c#, forms

I have a easy homework assignment, I have to make a parent form in C# that will have three text boxes where I enter data into each box, then I hit a process button and it will send that data to a child form displaying the same information in the three boxes in the child form.  I have the program working, however part of the assignment is that when the child form is active the parent form is to be hidden and then when I close the child form the parent returns.  I am not sure how do to this?  Any help?

Thanks.

Here is my code for the parent form...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chapter_15_Ex.Child_Parent_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void processToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string name;
            string address;
            int ccnum;

            name = Convert.ToString(txtName.Text);
            address = Convert.ToString(txtAddress.Text);
            ccnum = Convert.ToInt32(txtCreditCard.Text);

            Form2 childform = new Form2();
            //childform.MdiParent = Form1;
            childform.Show();

            childform.txtOutputName.Text = name;
            childform.txtOutputAddress.Text = address;
            childform.txtOutputCreditCard.Text = Convert.ToString(ccnum);          



        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since this is for homework, I'll explain it instead of providing the code.

Here are the steps:

1. Create an instance of `Form2` *(you already have that)*
2. Hide the current form *(there's a method you can call on* `this.` *)*
3. Show `Form2`, but then stop the current form until `Form2` closes - hint: there's a different call than `childForm.Show()`, but it's named similarly, and it prevents the code in `Form1` from continuing until the child form is closed.
4. Show the current form again *(different method on* `this.` *; opposite of the one from step 2)*

Comment: Ok I am getting close, I got the Parent to disappear when the child opens, but when I close the child the parent doesn't return.  A quick hint, does all the code I need go into form1 process button or will there need to be some code also inserted into the child exit button other than this.Close?

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Its working, but is this what you were talking about?

 Form2 childform = new Form2();
            //childform.MdiParent = Form1;            
            this.Hide();
           
            
                        

            childform.txtOutputName.Text = name;
            childform.txtOutputAddress.Text = address;
            childform.txtOutputCreditCard.Text = Convert.ToString(ccnum);

            childform.ShowDialog();
            this.Show();


            
        }